# compilation errors due to my if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, compiler-errors, compilation

I clearly don't understand what I am doing here... I am pretty certain that my errors are only in the code I included, but I do have other classes also. If I could rename this to a better title, let me know, Or if I can include any more info let me know. From what I see on this website, I believe you guys will know exactly what the compilation errors mean, and know what I did wrong.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
public class Shape
{
   public static void init( String args[] )
   {
      Shape[] shapes = new Shape[ 4 ];
      shapes[ 0 ] = new Circle( 22, 88, 4 );
      shapes[ 1 ] = new Square( 71, 96, 10 );
      shapes[ 2 ] = new Sphere( 8, 89, 2 );
      shapes[ 3 ] = new Cube( 79, 61, 8 );

      for ( Shape currentShape : shape );
      {
         System.out.printf( "%s: %s", 
         currentShape.getName(), currentShape );

         Object localObject;

         if ( currentShape objectof TwoDimensionalShape )
         { 
             localObject = (TwoDimensionalShape)currentShape; 

            TwoDimensionalShape twoDimensionalShape = 
               ( TwoDimensionalShape ) currentShape;

            System.out.printf( "%s's area is %s\n", 
               currentShape.getName(), twoDimensionalShape.getArea() );
         } 

         if ( currentShape objectof ThreeDimensionalShape; )
         {
            ThreeDimensionalShape threeDimensionalShape = 
               ( ThreeDimensionalShape ) currentShape;

            System.out.printf( "%s's area is %s\n", 
               currentShape.getName(), threeDimensionalShape.getArea() );
            System.out.printf( "%s's volume is %s\n",
               currentShape.getName(), 
               threeDimensionalShape.getVolume() );
         } 

         System.out.println();
      } 
   } 
}
```

My compilation errors:

```
ShapeTest.java:21: error: ')' expected
         if ( currentShape objectof TwoDimensionalShape )
                          ^
ShapeTest.java:21: error: ';' expected
         if ( currentShape objectof TwoDimensionalShape )
                                                       ^
ShapeTest.java:21: error: variable declaration not allowed here
         if ( currentShape objectof TwoDimensionalShape )
                                    ^
ShapeTest.java:33: error: ')' expected
         if (( currentShape objectof ThreeDimensionalShape; ))
                                    ^
ShapeTest.java:33: error: illegal start of expression
         if (( currentShape objectof ThreeDimensionalShape; ))
                                                          ^
ShapeTest.java:33: error: illegal start of expression
         if (( currentShape objectof ThreeDimensionalShape; ))
                                                             ^
6 errors
```

Comment: `instanceof`, not `objectof`

Comment: compilation error means there are some mistake in your code due to which java compiler is not able to compile that code. For example it can be missing semicolon at end of statement etc

Comment: @ajb Thank you! that fixed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java has an `instanceof` operator instead of `objectof`

In Line 21 Replace `if (currentShape objectof TwoDimensionalShape)` with 
`if(currentShape instanceof TwoDimensionalShape){ //more code }`

In Line 33 `if (currentShape objectof ThreeDimensionalShape;)` with 
`if(currentShape instanceof ThreeDimensionalShape){ //more code }`

Comment: Thank you! Your answer helped me, I thumbed up your answer. I am not sure why my question is in the negative....

Comment: Java is a strongly typed language. If you are not using an IDE like eclipse please do so. The IDE will tell you exactly what is wrong with your syntax. The question is in the negative probably because the mistake is very basic. Dont worry just use any IDE you like. You'll be comfortable with the syntax in a few days.

Answer (score 2):

There's no `objectof` operator in Java, I think you meant `instanceof`. Also, there's a misplaced semicolon inside one of the conditions. Rewrite the conditions like this:

```
if (currentShape instanceof TwoDimensionalShape)
if (currentShape instanceof ThreeDimensionalShape)
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer helped me, however I would like to say that a comment aftwards saying "//body of code here". As a newbie it was a little confusing but I figured it out. I thumbed up your answer. I am not sure why my question is in the negative....

Comment: @GeekyDewd sorry, I should have been more explicit, but you managed to understand it :) . I upvoted your answer, a downvote was not deserved.